# Blank spaces in ajax request with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making an ajax request and I have some problems, this is my jquery code:

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/SearchService.svc/search?keyword=my search keywords";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json".......
.....
```

When making this request I sometimes have blank spaces in my search (var url) and then the keywords get cutted so in the example above for example it just searches for "my". I understand this is a quite simple question and that must be an easy solution. Just couldn't find a solution...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should consider using a standard query string format, i.e. `http://www.domain.com/SearchService.svc?search=my search keywords` (note the question mark), that, together with Pekka's answer is probably the best solution.

Comment: updated the question, had just written the wrong url..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI):

```
var url = encodeURI("http://www.domain.com/SearchService.svc/search=my search keywords");
```

This encodes the URL and converts the blanks and any other 'unsafe' character for URL usage.

See also [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for safely encoding data to be inserted into a URI.

Comment: I know this is probably way late but I just saw this when I had a similar question `escape` has been deprecated and replaced with encodeURI for this application

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the search keyword in the URL but the right thing to do is to add `search` as a parameter to the ajax request.

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/SearchService.svc/search=my search keywords";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: { "search" : "my search keywords" }
        dataType: "json".......
```

Comment: it appears he's not using a standard query-string, so that wouldn't work

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/SearchService.svc/search?keyword=" 
    + encodeURIComponent("my search keywords");
```

While escape() might as well work for you, there are situations that only encodeURIComponent() will work, such as for characters & = + etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert whitespaces in url format. For each whitespace char use %20 instead:

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/SearchService.svc/search=my%20search%20keywords";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json".......
.....
```

Or if you want to make it in a more automatic way just use the javascript function `escape()` like Felix suggested.

Comment: there's a javascript function that does this, I think it's called escape.

Comment: @row yes you're correct. I couldn't recall the name of the function.