# Autocomplete not allowing spaces

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete in my site like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
        $this.autocomplete({              
            minLength: 1,                                               
        source: "{site_url}publish/my_autocomplete?key=" + $this.attr('id')
        })
    });     
})
```

It is working fine but when there is a word 'harley motor' and if I have typed 'ey ' with space it is not displaying. Any suggestions as to how I can select `harley motor` by just typing `ey` with a trailing space?

Comment: Maybe the server side code isn't sending results try debugging to verify this. In such case it's not related to jQuery but rather the server side logic.

Answer (score 2):

The URL needs to be escaped, since not only you have the issue:

[Blank spaces in ajax request with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008084/blank-spaces-in-ajax-request-with-jquery)

You need to **escape**:

```
source: escape("{site_url}publish/my_autocomplete?key=" + $this.attr('id'))
```

Comment: But it gives me error like The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure by just looking at your code. But it seems like you might be having problems posting spaces. Try using `encodeURIComponent` to encode your spaces before posting to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to find where the problem is, server side or client side..

If you get `Request.Params["term"]` value in server side that contains the user entered data with space, then you need to think about where the server side logic is error.

Otherwise, it might be an issue in client side, somewhere the entered text got spaces removed.

**Note:** `Request.Params` here I used is specific to ASP.Net and I am not sure about what server side technology you are using. But every language might have a equivalent code to check the request value

Comment: can you fiddle that..??plz

Comment: @Gautam3164, I am asking you to check at server side code written. I have no idea what technology do you use for server side processing.

Comment: Murali I think its not the prob with server side...bec iam using like $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(col4) FROM data_table WHERE col4 LIKE '%$name%'"; where $name is the word we have typed

Comment: @Gautam3164, I dont think there is a issue with Autocomplete plugin. It sends correct value to server. Check this out http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote and type a value with space and also see the request to the server with tool like `Firebug`. It sends the `term` parameter with the spaces encoded as `+`

Comment: @Gautam3164, You need to debug and verify your server side code.